# How to show pictures based on what answer filled in on the form?

Tags: php, html

I have 8 buttons, each button can be clicked, when you made your selection you go search, after you searched I need to show pictures based on what buttons are clicked before searching. I already have button that has be choosen in a array in PHP, but I dont know how to show the picture that has to be showed of depending on what buttons are used.

```
    <form id="search" action="programmer.php" method="get">
    <div data-toggle="buttons">

        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-4">    
                    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg-lg">
                        <input type="checkbox"style="display: none;" name="lang[]" value="html" autocomplete="off">HTML
                    </label> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg-lg">
                        <input type="checkbox" style="display: none;" name="lang[]" value="css" autocomplete="off">CSS
                    </label> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg-lg">
                        <input type="checkbox" style="display: none;" name="lang[]" value="javascript" autocomplete="off">Javascript
                    </label> 
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="container"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" >
    </div>
```

This is the PHP only showing off that I got the arrays:

```
<?php
print_r($_GET["lang"]); 
?>
```

Comment: The images should be shown at the same page or Is there a redirect to a new page?
You can save the path in a variable in php and the use it in the html code <img src='<?php echo $path;?>'>

Comment: Is there any code missing in your question, such as JavaScript? Your buttons are labels, so I am assuming you have some JavaScript to indicate which were clicked? Or is that the answer you are looking for? And you are in fact sending the entire array of data except for the ones you clicked? Either way, you must have some existing functionality regarding your buttons?

Comment: It is redirecting to a new page. There is no code missing, you can see which buttons are clicked because i added a bootstrap class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `style="display: none;"` so that checkbox are visible in the web page.Insert the name of your images in value attribute of the checkbox. When you will click on search button all the images selected in checkbox list will be displayed on the next web page.
Add following code to the `programmer.php`

```
  <?php
$path_to_img_dir="path1/";
$arr=$_GET['lang'];
foreach($arr as $val){
    echo sprintf("<img src='%s%s.jpg' /><br>",$path_to_img_dir,$val);
}
?>
```

Comment: I left the $path_to_img_dir empty and now its working TY

Answer (score 0):

You can save the path in a variable in php and the use it in the html code `<img src='<?php echo $path;?>'>`

Comment: Yeah, but how do show the right picture based on what html element is send?

Comment: add a unique name to each checkbox. Only the checked ones are send. So you can check the request in php. Only the clicked one should be there.
Like here in the example https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_checkbox